# WatchGuard Firebox VPN will not connect if signed in as a domain user

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, ssl

We are trying to connect to a client's network using their WatchGuard VPN, and we are experiencing a really odd error which some other people seem to have had, but haven't shared their solutions.

When we sign in as a domain user, or a domain admin, on the client PC the WatchGuard FireBox client gets stuck at "Starting VPN with SSL", although if I sign in as a local administrator (not a domain user with Local Admin rights, but the built in Administrator account), the connection goes straight through, on the same PC.

Does anyone know what prevents the connection when signed in with a domain account? I've looked at the logs, but the error logs are not very detailed... at all...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which kind of VPN are we talking about exactly?

Comment: All the client has told me is that it is a WatchGuard VPN built on top of OpenVPN, sorry I can't elaborate on that more...

Comment: If it's affecting any/all domain users, but not local users, then it's most likely something being applied to the user-level via Group Policies.  You should use GPresult to determine what policies are being applied.  Things like Proxies may be getting forced on the user, etc.  Here's a  GPO I'd start with looking into: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732613(v=ws.10).aspx,

Comment: have you made sure the user's certificate store contains the certificate?